# Change user agent on FMX.WebBrowser?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I need to change the user agent on the FMX.WebBrowser for a wide range testing app on a mobile devices.

- Is there a way to change FMX.WebBrowser user agent ?

Comment: I think some Delphi source files can be modified to add this feature but that depends on what platform(s) you're interested in.

Comment: Well.. tried to find a way, but so far it looks like a whole rewriting on the FXM.WebBrowser and the rest, yet - so far I cant even find a starting point :'(